# Dealing with extreme heat and pressure in an underground colony on Venus

Tags: biology, physics, chemistry, space-colonization, astrophysics

A colony has been constructed by robots for human habitation deep under the surface of Venus. They are totally sealed off from the surface, and the galaxy beyond, and live like a ship in a bottle

What theoretical technological solutions could they develop and deploy to protect a city sized space from the extreme heat and air pressure?

xx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's mostly a matter of having insulation and multiple stages of cooling systems, and power systems that can run hot enough to use the surface as a heat sink while delivering enough power to run those cooling systems (**lots** of power), but *why*? Any interruption or shortage of power or failure of the cooling systems will quickly destroy the colony, and the colony won't be particularly hidden, being a massive heat signature on a planet that should be near thermal equilibrium.

Comment: And why would you go underground; you've already got pressure equivalent to kilometer-deep sea water, and you want to add the weight of rock on top?  Won't be any cooler down there, either; Venus still has a hot core...

Comment: Maybe if you had something like the entropy flaw in A. Reynold's books. The more they computed, the more heat could be "lost", and since the cryogenic temps allowed for faster computing... well, that can cause problems. Eventually.

Answer (score 4):

The heat is more of an issue than the pressure. Mechanical components can withstand significantly more pressure than they can heat. There is no need for such a colony to have the 1 atmosphere of pressure we humans evolved in (humans can survive in higher/lower pressure environments, it is the rapid transition between pressures which causes most issues). The atmospheric pressure on Venus is around 92 times of that at sea level on Earth at its lowest points. Building your city high on a mountain would reduce some of the pressure. The highest point on Venus, Maxwell Montes, has a pressure of 45 bars. More of the strain can be countered by simply adding additional atmosphere within the city. Filling the city with additional air could reduce or eliminate the external pressure. A city high on a Venusian mountain with 10 atmosphere’s worth of internal pressure would severely reduce the external pressure. Higher elevations are also colder.

Heat is an issue for several reasons. While people like to state that Venus is hot enough to melt lead, it is not hot enough to melt most metals. Zinc would melt as well, but most others (copper, aluminum, gold, iron, nickel, silver, titanium, etc.) would be fine. It would prevent the use of plastics and rubbers, but those are processed primarily from petrochemicals and plant-based excretions, both in short supply on Venus. Ceramics would do just fine. Computer processors tend to like to be kept cool, especially when it comes to quantum computing. Lubricants would likewise have issues, as many oils polymerize at high temps. Any external equipment would need to be heat resistant to an extreme degree. Humans need a very narrow range of temperature to survive. The same is true for the plants and animals they would require for sustenance. Getting to that range is difficult as heat always attempts to balance out. Water is also lacking on Venus, so they would need a 100% efficient method of recycling their water as even a 0.1% loss each year would be noticed after a few centuries with no method of replacing what was lost.

Heat pumps move heat from one location to another. You could simply pump the heat outside of your city, through some super-insulation, and hand wave it as good. A few lines about the heat pumps needing to run constantly, and how each city expansion requires the installation of new insulation, and you are good to go. Peltier motors move heat from one side to the other, making the opposite side cold. You can do almost anything with enough power. If you have fusion as an energy source, you have plenty of power. Well… normally you do, but you need access to hydrogen in its various forms, which is in short supply on Venus. Solar power is out. Wind might be somewhat effective with the density of the atmosphere, but wind speeds at the surface are slow. You could have the windmill blades operating as your heat emitters, pumping cooled gas and electricity to the underground city. As long as the blades are hotter than the air, they will emit heat. Make them out of tungsten and you never have to worry about them melting.

Not all solutions need be technological. A human population genetically separated from the main group would begin to experience genetic drift. This would be increased in such a hostile environment, as those ill-suited for survival would die off. If such adaptations are not fast enough, genetic engineering could help the population initially. Give your people, animals, and plants genes from desert and deep sea dwelling organisms which make them better suited for such a hot high pressure environment. There are still upper limits to temperature when it comes to human survivability, but there is room for improvement. Honestly, it might be better to have them colonize a rogue planet drifting out between the stars. They would still have to live underground or in domes due to the cold, but it would be a heck of a lot easier than colonizing Venus. Since most of the atmosphere would freeze without a sun to warm it, they would have a near vacuum to deal with instead of extreme pressure. It would make it easy for them to provide atmosphere for their cities. They could scoop up the frozen/liquid nitrogen and oxygen and simply heat it up a bit. If they are not emitting many signals, they could drift for eons without anyone noticing them. We already have the technology to survive in space so you could use known tech instead of inventing new stuff. Without a nearby star, most of the radiation concerns are moot. If the planet has a decent sized moon, you could still have geothermal power providing ideal areas for colonization. This would open up fusion, fission, and geothermal as power sources, but eliminate solar, hydro, and wind. Eventually their planet could slingshot around a micro-black hole and return to the Solar system if you wanted to show how their time changed them.

Comment: Upvote for TUNGSTEN WINDMILL!  cue guitar divebomb and metal power chords